# Using AJAX to load/reload a .jsp within a parent page, the reloaded child does not recognize parent variables.

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax, jsp

any help or pointing in the right direction would be appreciated. I have found some questions in the same vein that remain unanswered.

I have a JSP that I am using in tandem with Servlets the query information from a database on load and pass that data to various attributes via the ".setAttribute()" method. This allows me to use inline code execution and access these data members.

Within the page I also use the `<%@include file="xxx.jsp" %>` to pull in another file, which has inline code that accesses the data members generated by the parent .jsp. On the first page load, (where it is using the `<%include>`) the page loads as expected, recognizing the local data.

However, when I try to reload the child .jsp file using AJAX (via jQuery) it does not recognize the local variables of the parent .jsp.

Here is how I am reloading the .jsp:

```
var progressAJAX = function(callingButton){
            $("#progress").load("partials/progressCard.jsp", {
                    moduleNumber: $(callingButton).data("moduleNumber")
                },
                function () {


                }
            );
        }
```

and here is how it is included otherwise:

```
    <div id="progress">
        <%@include file="partials/progressCard.jsp"%>
        </div>
```

and here is the child file being included: (You can see all of the local variables that are trying to be accessed from the parent)

```
<c:choose>
                <c:when test="${moduleNumber != null && moduleNumber < moduleArray.length - 1}">
                    <c:set var="module" value="${moduleArray[moduleNumber]}"/>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <c:set var="module" value="${moduleArray[0]}"/>
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col"><img src="images/activity_0.gif" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="col" id="lessonProgressWheelContainer"></div>
                        <h2>${module.name}</h2>
                        <div>${module.description}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <%--<div class="row" id="lessonProgressWheelContainer"></div>--%>
                <div class="row justify-content-evenly">
                    <c:forEach var="activity" items="${module.activityArray}" varStatus="loop">
                        <div class="col activity"><a
                                href="activity?id=${activity.id}&moduleID=${module.moduleID}&round=1"><img
                                src="images/activity_${loop.index + 1}.gif" alt=""></a></div>
                    </c:forEach>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: When the child jsp is rendered via the AJAX call the parent context does not exist so those variables defined from the parent are not accessible.  What is the error?  You'll need some other parent which can set up those same variables.  The ajax parent could be another jsp which includes the same child jsp, or a servlet which creates those variables and puts them in the correct scope for the child jsp.

Comment: The problem is I don't want to set up the variables (which are queried from the database) more than once. Is there a way the servlet being called by the AJAX could simply re-up the variables from the parent JSP?

Comment: Not directly from the parent jsp (which should be stateless to avoid threading issues).  One solution could be to cache the variables to avoid another database call.

Comment: What do you mean "cache" the variables?

Comment: For example, the servlet which calls the database and sets up the variables for the  original parent request could put those variables in the session scope.  The servlet which handles the child request could pull those variables from the session and put them in request scope (or whatever scope the child is expecting).